# Night light circuit wih switching bulbs

Tags: switching, electrical, ldr, light-sensor, spdt

How can I connect a night light circuit such that one bulb is lit up on a sunny day and one is only lit up at night so that the two lights don't light up simultaneously? Also, can I use a SPDT switch and how?

I plan to use the circuit below as a reference.

Your help is appreciated.

[image: Automatic night light circuit]

Comment: So basically you're asking us to design you a circuit for that? There are plenty of night light projects described on the internet, go look at some of those. The circuit you included is extremely basic and will drain the battery even when the LED is off. Using that "as a reference" just because that's what you found is a bit lazy. Either find a project that does what you want and build that **exactly** or spend some time to study existing circuits instead of just leaving your assignment here for us to finish.

Answer (score 0):

The circuit that you've added to your question is a bit too basic as @Bimpelrekkie mentioned in the comment. but you can still use it with all down-sides that it have.

With a little modification you can add a relay to that circuit so when the relay is energized one LED will be on and when it's not the other LED will be on:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3NDMn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>